# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit" inside ios directory

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have flutter app and I am getting the following error when I run the command:
pod install --repo-update

Here are is the error I am getting:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_facebook_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`) was resolved to 4.3.0, which depends on
      FBSDKLoginKit (~> 13)

    flutter_login_facebook (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_login_facebook/ios`) was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
      FBSDKLoginKit (~> 12.3)
```

The error started appearing after I upgraded to the latest flutter packages.
Here is the packages I am using in pubspeck.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  badges: ^2.0.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0
  cloud_functions: ^3.1.0
  connectivity_plus: ^2.0.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  device_info_plus: ^3.2.2
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+2
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4
  firebase_auth: ^3.2.0
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.3.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.0.6
  firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.5.0+14
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.1.0
  flash: ^2.0.3
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.0
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.4.0
  flutter_login_facebook: ^1.2.0
  flutter_markdown: ^0.6.8
  flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  flutterfire_ui: ^0.3.4
  freezed_annotation: ^1.1.0
  geocoding: ^2.0.4
  geolocator: ^8.2.0
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.1
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  hooks_riverpod: ^1.0.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  linkable: ^3.0.1
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^5.0.6295
  open_mail_app: ^0.4.5
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  package_info_plus: ^1.3.0
  pattern_formatter: ^2.0.0
  permission_handler: ^8.2.6
  photo_view: ^0.13.0
  purchases_flutter: ^3.5.0
  rate_my_app: ^1.1.1+1
  share: ^2.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  timeago: ^3.1.0
  tuple: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.20
  uuid: ^3.0.5
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mockito: ^5.1.0
```

I tried the following things:

- deleted Podfile.lock
- ran flutter clean
- inside Podfile I have (platform :ios, '11.0')

Thanks for your help in advance.

This is what I get when I run flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-x64, locale en-AE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how I solved the problem based on a suggestion by "darwin-morocho
/flutter-facebook-auth"

> you must remove flutter_login_facebook from your pubspec.yaml, also
> flutter_facebook_auth must be in your dependencies

Answer (score 21):

just delete your ios workspace , pods file and pod.lock then,
change the platform :ios, '12.0' in your podfile

after execute pod install and run the project its work for me

Comment: Just changing to 12.0 did it for me.

Comment: changing to 12.0 and deleting pod.lock worked for me. thank you @Kavindu!

Comment: Thanks, changing the platform version to 12.0 worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I just updated ios platform from 11 to 12 in podfile and after that run pod update it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Follow These Steps :

1 . `Flutter clean`
2 . `Flutter pub get`

3 . In ios/podfile :
Change : `#platform :ios, '11.0'`
To : `platform :ios, '12.0'`

4 . then run this command : `pod install`

> Note : Select the directory to **<your_project>/iOS/**

YOU SHOULD ABLE TO SOLVE THE ISSUE NOW